# Gwt / Gxt layout with mixed behaviours

Tags: java, html, gwt, gxt

I'm looking for a layout that contains two widgets, one which is able to define its own size and expand or shrink as wanted, and the other which will fit the remaining space.

From what I gathered, it's a mix of two different behaviours, as a layout usually either fixes its children size, or allows them to fix it.

So how could I achieve that ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand exactly but I think `BorderLayout` might work using EAST, NORTH, SOUTH or WEST panel with CENTER panel.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the outline of what I'm using for this requirement ... the key is to use the `VerticalLayoutData` class to specify "size to contents" or "use remaining space".:

```
...
<ui:with
  type='com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.container.VerticalLayoutContainer.VerticalLayoutData'
  field='fillRemainingVLD'>
  <ui:attributes
    height='1'
    width='1'/>
</ui:with>
<ui:with
  type='com.sencha.gxt.widget.core.client.container.VerticalLayoutContainer.VerticalLayoutData'
  field='sizeToContentsVLD'>
  <ui:attributes
    height='-1'
    width='1'/>
</ui:with>
...
<gxtcontainer:VerticalLayoutContainer>
  <gxtcontainer:child layoutData='{sizeToContentsVLD}'>
    ... your widget goes here ...
  </gxtcontainer:child>
  <gxtcontainer:child layoutData='{fillRemainingVLD}'>
    ... your widget goes here ...
  </gxtcontainer:child>
</gxtcontainer:VerticalLayoutContainer>
```